# problemas al enviar adjuntos en funcion python de envio de mails (gmail)

Tags: python, email, gmail, smtplib

tengo esta función de envio de emails a través de gmail en python, pero me da un error al indicar la ruta donde están los adjuntos.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import os

class MailGmail:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        ...
        
    def send(self, emailFrom, password, emailTo, subject, email_content, attachments):
               
        mensaje = MIMEMultipart()
        mensaje['Subject'] = subject
        mensaje['From'] = emailFrom
        mensaje['To'] = emailTo
        mensaje.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        mensaje.set_payload(email_content)
        
        for attach in attachments:
            part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
            part.set_payload(open(attach, "rb").read())
            encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= {0}".format(os.path.basename(attach)))
            mensaje.attach(part)        
        
        s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
        s.starttls()
        s.login(mensaje['From'], password)
        s.sendmail(mensaje['From'], mensaje['To'], mensaje.as_string())
        print("Mensaje enviado")
```

aca ejecuta la funcion con los parametros necesarios

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mail = "destinatario@destino.cl"
    subject = 'Ejemplo mail de pruebas con HTML'

    gmail           = MailGmail()
    emailFrom       = 'mimail@gmail.com'
    password        = "lasuperclavedegmail"
    emailTo         = mail
    subject         = "este es el subject"
    email_content   = """
                        <html>
                            <head>
                                <title>Ejemplo de envio de emails con plantilla html</title>
                            </head>
                            <body>
                                <h1>este es un texto con formato</h1>
                                <table id="top-table" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <p><a href="#">ejemplo de tabla</a></p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </body>
                        </html>
                      """
    attachments     = "C:\AppServer\imagen.jpg"
    
    gmail.send(emailFrom, password, emailTo, subject, email_content, attachments)
```

al parecer el error es que no puede reconocer la ruta completa donde esta el attach
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C'

el codigo funciona bien si no le especifico la ruta del adjunto a la funcion.

alguna idea de porque esta pasando esto?
Saludos y gracias por leer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución:

```
attachments     = ["C:\AppServer\imagen.jpg"]
```

`attachments` debe ser una lista y en el código es simplemente un string.

Comment: Hola Gracias por la ayuda. efectivamente no es un string lo que tengio que enviar. Al modificar como lo indicas, ya no me reclama por el archivo, sin embargo, me aparece un nuevo error   
    raise TypeError("Attach is not valid on a message with a"
TypeError: Attach is not valid on a message with a non-multipart payload   sabras a que se refiere esto. Nuevamente gracias por la ayuda.